# Increment date when click on button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing Cordova based application. In my app, I have a problem with date increment.[image]

In the above image, I need to increment and decrement date when click on forward and backward buttons. Any one please help...

Comment: Do you have any partly working code? If so, please [edit] to include in the question.

Comment: I have no idea to start this...So, I didn't start

Comment: What is the code that displays the current date ?

Comment: I used JavaScript Date() function.

Answer (score 2):

**8640000 milli seconds= 24*60*60*1000**

For Increment Date :

```
var dataI = new Date();
var i = dataI.valueOf() + 86400000 ;
dataI = new Date( i);
```

For Decrement Date :

```
var dataI = new Date();
var i = dataI.valueOf() - 86400000 ;
dataI = new Date( i);
```

jsfiddle.net/zpmu0m51

Comment: The question is vague. This answer only addresses the calculation not the ui mechanics of getting the button click to change the date.

Comment: Great. You have a better answer if you put that link in the answer. You can edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, here you have a demo, I suppose you use jQuery

HTML

```
<button id="decr">
  decr
</button>
<span id="date"></span>
<button id="incr">
  incr
</button>
```

JS

```
var date = new Date();
$("#date").text(date.toDateString());

$('#decr').on('click', function() {
  date = new Date(Date.parse($('#date').text()));
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  $('#date').text(date.toDateString());
});

$('#incr').on('click', function() {
  date = new Date(Date.parse($('#date').text()));
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  $('#date').text(date.toDateString());
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4hqyq8qm/1/